# Swift- Check which button is selected in different class using if-statement

Tags: swift, if-statement, uibutton, switch-statement

I have 4 different buttons that lead to the same view controller `SearchPage()`,
thus I assigned these buttons in the main `yearOne` class like this:

`class yearOne: UICollectionViewController`:

```
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        var tagVal : NSInteger = sender.tag
        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            print("ONEEE")
            let destination = SearchPage()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        case 1:
            print("TWOOO")
            let destination = SearchPage()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        case 2:
            print("THREEE")
            let destination = SearchPage()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        case 3:
            print("FOURRR")
            let destination = SearchPage()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        default:
            let destination = SearchPage()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

each of the buttons is in different classes

`class fallQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`:

```
    let addButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()//frame: CGRect(x: 345, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30))
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "addicon"), for: .normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        button.tag = 0
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yearOne.buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

`class winterQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`:

```
    let addButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()//frame: CGRect(x: 345, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30))
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "addicon"), for: .normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        button.tag = 1
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yearOne.buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

and so on with the third and fourth buttons. Anyways the button does work and each one prints out correctly and sends me to the `SearchPage()`

However in my `SearchPage()` class, I'm trying to recall the sender.tag?? so that I can use if/else statement on which button was pressed/selected.

```
    let mainvc = yearOne()
    let vc = fallQuarterCell()
    let vc2 = winterQuarterCell()
    let vc3 = springQuarterCell()
    let vc4 = summerQuarterCell()

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if (mainvc.tagValue == 0){
            if (resultSearchController.isActive){

                vc.data.append(filteredCourses[indexPath.row])
                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc.data, forKey: "SavedArray")

                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }
            else{
                vc.data.append(allCourses[indexPath.row] as! String)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc.data, forKey: "SavedArray")

                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }
        }
        else if (mainvc.tagValue == 1){
            if (resultSearchController.isActive){
                vc2.data.append(filteredCourses[indexPath.row])
                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc2.data, forKey: "SavedArray2")
                vc2.tableView.reloadData()
                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            else{
                vc2.data.append(allCourses[indexPath.row] as! String)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc2.data, forKey: "SavedArray2")
                vc2.tableView.reloadData()
                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }

    }
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I can approach this? Right now because I added the `tagVal` inside the button func, the `yearOne` aka `mainvc` doesn't seem to have a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a value on your SearchPage view controller to capture the tag.

```
class SearchPage: UIViewController {
  var tag: Int?
  ...
}
```

Then in your switch statement you should do something like this.

```
case 0:
  print("ONEEE")
  let destination = SearchPage()
  destination.tag = sender.tag // <- update the tag value here
  navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
```

You should also remove the `let mainVC = yearOne()` as that is a new instance of the `yearOne` class and has no bearing on the previous `yearOne` that you created.